# Can a function receive an object as an argument in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arguments

```
var currentbutton = {};
function setPreset(obj) {
    try{
        if(obj.name===name && obj.value===value){
            //log.error("preset array's OID at position ["+index+"]     is"+presets[index].name +" and the value stored is "+presets[index].value);
            currentbutton.name=obj.name;
            currentbutton.value=obj.value;
            log.error("currentbutton name= "+currentbutton.name+     "currentbutton value= " + currentbutton.value );
        }
        else
            log.error("adklafjklajkl");
    }
    catch(ie){
        log.error("couldn't set preset");
    }

presets.forEach(function(obj));
```

I know there must be mistakes in this code that I wrote, first of all, I was told that the function need to receive an object as an argument, which I have no idea how to pass it to the function. I tried google, but I did not find any relevant information on whether a function can receive an object as an argument.
presets is an array which contains objects which has two properties (called "name" and "value")
basically, the array Presets goes through its enumerated list of variables with forEach, and compare if the argument obj's name and value are identical or not to any of the objects stored inside the array, if they are identical, set the currentbutton's name and value to the one inside the argument obj. Then we will have other functions which will operate on currentbutton that i don't have to worry about.
I know it's not really clear because I am not even sure if that's what is wanted of me.

Comment: Yes, you can pass anything to a function call.

Comment: how do I pass an object to a function then? is it supposed to be like function setPreset(obj){}?

Comment: Of course you can. `setPreset({name:"hello", value:"world"})`. Notice that your `forEach` loop is totally screwed up.

Comment: the last line of code doesn't mean anything though.

Comment: @Bergi sorry but I am a programming newb, how do I declare it when declaring a function? is function setPreset(obj){} correct?

Comment: @apsillers but setpreset must also get an argument when used no? if I just write presets.forEach(setPreset); then how do I compare the  argument object with the objects in array Presets?

Comment: Are you missing a closing brace? Should the `forEach` call be inside the definition of `setPreset`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't quite understand how `forEach` works. The `forEach` method takes a function as its argument:

```
[1,2,3].forEach(function(item) {
    alert(item);
});
```

That function passed into `forEach` is given an argument itself. Here, I've named it `item`. The `forEach` method *repeatedly invokes* the function and supplies a successive member of the array as the first argument each time it is invoked.

Now, instead of passing in a literal function, I can use a variable to hold my function:

```
var alertStuff = function(item) {
    alert(item);
}
```

Then, I use that function (referring to it by variable name) in `forEach`:

```
[1,2,3].forEach(alertStuff);

// is the same as...
[1,2,3].forEach(function(item) {
    alert(item);
});
```

Thus, you want to use `presets.forEach(setPreset);`.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to explain to me, if I could vote, id upvote you

Answer (score 1):

Define a function which accepts a paramter

```
function myNewFunc(obj){
  alert(obj.myFirstProp);
}
```

Define an object which we are going to pass as an argument to the above function

```
var myObject = {
    myFirstProp: "testing"
};
```

Call the function and pass the object as an argument

```
myNewFunc(myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets were screwed up and you invoked `forEach` wrong.

```
var presets = [
  {name:'a', value:1},
  {name:'b', value:2},
  {name:'c', value:3},
];
var currentbutton = {};
function setPreset(obj) {
  try{
    if(obj.name===name && obj.value===value){
      //log.error("preset array's OID at position ["+index+"]     is"+presets[index].name +" and the value stored is "+presets[index].value);
      currentbutton.name=obj.name;
      currentbutton.value=obj.value;
      log.error("currentbutton name= "+currentbutton.name+     "currentbutton value= " + currentbutton.value );
    } else { // syntax error, opening { of else block was missing
      log.error("adklafjklajkl");
    }
  } // syntax error, closing } of try block was missing
  catch(ie){
    log.error("couldn't set preset");
  }
} // syntax error, closing } of function was missiong

presets.forEach(setPreset);
```